# How to access the data in the associated models using ExtJS stores?

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, extjs4.2

I have several components, mainly home made, in a page. Each one has its own store+model+view. For performance reasons, I want to make a single AJAX request to the backend in order to get all the data at once and then navigate through each data part and assign those parts to their corresponding component's stores.
But it seems I can't get / read those parts.
I've tried to follow the tips found here [Extjs4: How to share data between multiple stores or models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993003/extjs4-how-to-share-data-between-multiple-stores-or-models) but without any success.

The JSON data returned by the backend looks like:

```
{
  "success":true,
  "results":8,
  "data":[{
    "bv01":{
      "success":true,
      "count":1,
      "data":[{
        "active_learner_count":0,
        "connected_learner_count":0,
        "enrolled_learner_count":123999,
        "registered_learner_count":120098
      }]
    }
  },{
    "bv02":{
      "success":true,
      "count":1,
      "data":[{
          // Blabla
      }]
    }
  },{ 
    // 6 other embedded responses
  }]
}
```

Here's a snippet of the stores / models I use:

The inner-most model, holding the data that are linked to a template (not shown here):

```
Ext.define('Ckls.module.Graphs.Square.model.Learner', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: [
    {name: 'hugeRectCount', type: 'int', mapping: 'registered_learner_count'},
    {name: 'bigRectCount', type: 'int', mapping: 'enrolled_learner_count'},
    {name: 'mediumRectCount', type: 'int', mapping: 'active_learner_count'},
    {name: 'smallRectCount', type: 'int', mapping: 'connected_learner_count'}
  ]
});
```

The composed model:

```
Ext.define('Reporting.Reporting.model.Kpi.Bv01', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields:[{
    name: "success",
    type: "auto"
  },{
    name: "count",
    type: "auto"
  }],
  hasMany: {
    model: 'Ckls.module.Graphs.Square.model.Learner',
    name: 'data'
  },
  belongsTo: 'Reporting.Reporting.model.Block'
});
```

The one-call model:

```
Ext.define('Reporting.Reporting.model.Block', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  hasOne: [{
    model: 'Reporting.Reporting.model.Kpi.Bv01',
    name : "bv01"
  },{
    model: 'Reporting.Reporting.model.Kpi.Bv02',
    name : "bv02"
  },{
    ... // several extra models inclusions come here
  }]
});
```

The store definition for the one-call initialization:

```
Ext.define('Reporting.Reporting.store.Blocks', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
  model: 'Reporting.Reporting.model.Block',
  proxy: {
    type  : 'ajax',
    reader: {
      type: 'json',
      root: 'data'
    },
    url: '/some_url.php?some_parameter=some_value'
  }
});
```

The controller:

```
Ext.define('Reporting.Reporting.controller.Reporting', {
  extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
  init: function() {
    // 'activities' is my main view
    this.control({
      'activities': {
        afterrender: this.initAllStores
    });
  },
  initAllStores: function() {
    var blockStore = Ext.create('Reporting.Reporting.store.Blocks');
    var blockStoreListeners = blockStore.on('load', this.blockStoreLoaded, this);
    blockStore.load();
  },
  blockStoreLoaded: function(store, records, successful, eOpts) {
    // As far as I can tell from the documentation, this should 
    // return the data as read in the sub-model but it throws an
    // "undefined" error
    var bv01results = store.data.getBbv01();
    Ext.log({msg:"bv01results", dump: bv01results});
    var bv01store = someFunctionToGetThatBv01Store();
    bv01store.loadRawData(bv01results);
  }
}
```

I don't know how to access the inner data and then load them into the bv01 store. In Chrome, the console gives the error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

### Edit

I've added a memory proxy to the models (as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19361382/2732205):

```
Ext.define('Reporting.Reporting.model.Kpi.Bv01', {
  // ....
  proxy: {
    type: 'memory',
    reader: {
      type: 'json'
    }
  }
}
```

And fixed the function call in the controller to get the data:

```
Ext.define('Reporting.Reporting.controller.Reporting', {
  // ....
  blockStoreLoaded: function(store, records, successful, eOpts) {
    var record0 = store.getAt(0);
    Ext.log({msg:"record0", dump: record0});

    // It seems that it's now trying to load the "bv01" from the
    // network instead of just reading it from the record
    var bv01results = record0.getBv01();
    Ext.log({msg:"bv01results", dump: bv01results});

    var bv01store = someFunctionToGetThatBv01Store();
    bv01store.loadRawData(bv01results);
  }
}
```

Now the console reads `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasId' of undefined`. From the searches I've made, this seems to appear when there is an attempt to read the data from the network.

I'm getting a bit further but I still have the feeling to being stuck...

Comment: Your question is  well formed but I beleive it could be a duplicate, there are alot of posts regarding ExtJs associations on [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=extjs+associations), they can be a bit of a pain sometimes.

Comment: You could make an Ajax call and load the data in each store using the success callback.

Comment: Thank you, both, for  your quick answers. I'm exploring the links you gave, Scriptable. Many of them have I already read, though. I think I'm getting something there. I'll post an answer if I find one by myself.

Comment: I've edited the question with my progress

Comment: Any help ? All the examples I came across deal either with "hasMany" associations -- which is not my case -- or with write / synchronization problems, which is not my case either.